# VBA Data Import from Google into Excel: Custom Time Ranges

Tags: html, excel, vba, web-scraping

For a VBA application in Excel, I am trying to include the "custom time range" function Google offers when narrowing down the search. So far, I am using the following code (see below), which allows to import "resultStats" from Google for a given search term into Excel but lacks the time range option.

In this specific case, I would need to determine the number of results/articles e.g. for "Elon Musk" between 01/01/2015 and 12/31/2015. Is there any practicable addition to the code below? And can this also be applied for the Google News tab instead of the regular Google Search results?

Many thanks in advance!

```
Sub Gethits()
Dim url As String, lastRow As Long
Dim XMLHTTP As Object, html As Object, objResultDiv As Object, objH3 As Object, link As Object
Dim start_time As Date
Dim end_time As Date
Dim var As String
Dim var1 As Object

lastRow = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

Dim cookie As String
Dim result_cookie As String

start_time = Time
Debug.Print "start_time:" & start_time

For i = 2 To lastRow

    url = "https://www.google.com/search?q=" & Cells(i, 1) & "&rnd=" & WorksheetFunction.RandBetween(1, 10000)

    Set XMLHTTP = CreateObject("MSXML2.serverXMLHTTP")
    XMLHTTP.Open "GET", url, False
    XMLHTTP.setRequestHeader "Content-Type", "text/xml"
    XMLHTTP.setRequestHeader "User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; rv:25.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/25.0"
    XMLHTTP.send

    Set html = CreateObject("htmlfile")
    html.body.innerHTML = XMLHTTP.responseText
    Set objResultDiv = html.getElementById("rso")
    Set var1 = html.getElementById("resultStats")
    Cells(i, 2).Value = var1.innerText

    DoEvents
Next

end_time = Time
Debug.Print "end_time:" & end_time

Debug.Print "done" & "Time taken : " & DateDiff("n", start_time, end_time)
MsgBox "done" & "Time taken : " & DateDiff("n", start_time, end_time)
```

End Sub

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you need URL encoding so a string as shown below works when you include your `cd_max` and `cd_min` parameters. You specify `news` with the parameter `tbm=nws`.

As @chillin mentions you can achieve encoding of parameters with `Application.Encodeurl()`.

I also tried the API method but with limited success. Though the dataRange filter can be passed in the sort parameter, you need to register for an API key , set up a custom search engine and set your requirements. Results are max 10 per query; there is an API call limit for free calls. You can specify a start number to get blocks of 10. You can also see what is URL encoded by running through the [Google APIs explorer - custom search](https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/#search/custom/m/customsearch/v1/search.cse.list). I found it only returned 2 results which was clearly not in the region of the expected number.

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub GetResultCount()
    Dim sResponse As String, html As HTMLDocument
    With CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")
        .Open "GET", "https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=elon+musk&safe=strict&biw=1163&bih=571&source=lnt&tbs=cdr%3A1%2Ccd_min%3A1%2F1%2F2015%2Ccd_max%3A12%2F31%2F2015&tbm=nws", False
        .setRequestHeader "If-Modified-Since", "Sat, 1 Jan 2000 00:00:00 GMT"
        .send
         sResponse = StrConv(.responseBody, vbUnicode)
    End With
    Set html = New HTMLDocument
    With html
        .body.innerHTML = sResponse
        Debug.Print .querySelector("#resultStats").innerText
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Might be worth mentioning that URL encoding can be achieved with `Application.Encodeurl()` in modern Excel versions.

Comment: @chillin  That is true. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your feedback. I have now amended the URL line as follows (including the Excel ENCODEURL function, which I applied directly for the input cells of the Excel spreadsheet) and it works perfectly:

```
url = "https://www.google.com/search?q=" & Cells(i, 1) & "&source=lnt&tbs=cdr%3A1%2Ccd_min%3A" & Cells(i, 2) & "%2Ccd_max%3A" & Cells(i, 3) & "&tbm=nws"
```